# How can I find the difference in years between two dates using Python? (Work out if a person is over 18)

Tags: python, debugging, datetime, if-statement, syntax-error

My question is if anyone can please help me to debug this piece of code:

```
import datetime
print ("What is your date of birth? ")
dateofbirth = input("Please type your date of birth in a YYYY-MM-DD format ")
year, month, day = map(int, dateofbirth.split('-'))
dateofbirth1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
today = datetime.date.today()
open('dateutil.tar').read()
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
difference_in_years = relativedelta(today, dateofbirth1).years
if difference_in_years < 18
print ("Sorry, you are not eligible to vote.")
else
print ("You are over 18 and thus eligible to vote.")
```

My objective is to try and write a piece of code that can work out if someone is over 18 and thus eligible to vote. This is meant to be achieved by asking the person to input their date of birth and then working out the difference in years between their birthdate and today's date, then using an IF statement to tell them whether or not they are able to vote (i.e. if the difference in years is more or less than 18).

Currently I am having several problems with debugging this code. Firstly, on line 10 there is a Syntax Error which I am unsure how to rectify. Secondly, if I remove the last 4 lines and run the code again I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\removed\canyouvote.py", line 8, in <module>
    open('dateutil.tar').read()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
```

However in all probability there are other mistakes that I am currently unable to pick up. Sadly as I am very new to programming, my knowledge and experience are not great and so any help would be greatly appreciated! While trying to research a solution I have attempted to use coding that I am unfamiliar with, so please correct me where I am wrong.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Well the `SyntaxError` is because [the syntax is erroneous](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) and what exactly are you trying to do with the file? You aren't assigning the contents to anything, what is the point of that line?

Comment: In Python, compound statements like `if` and `else` need a colon before the suite, and the suite has to be indented. See the [First Steps Towards Programming](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) section of the tutorial.

Comment: Also, why are you using `dateutil` at all here? Have you tried printing out what you get from `today - dateofbirth1` to see if it's something useful? (If you haven't gotten used to typing things into the interactive interpreter, sprinkling `print` calls in your code, or using the debugger, you're going to need to learn at least one, and eventually all three, before you'll be able to write even the most trivial programs successfully.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the `UnicodeDecodeError` is that you're trying to open and read a [tarball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing))—that is, a binary file—as if it were a text file.

When you do that, Python tries to interpret the arbitrary bytes of that file as if they represented characters in your default character set (cp1252), but that's going to give you an exception if you're lucky, or successfully give you complete garbage if you're not. Try opening `dateutil.tar` in a text editor to see how meaningful it is as text.

It's hard to say how to fix that, because it's not clear why you're trying to open and read that file in the first place. As [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) points out, you're not doing anything with the results. And I can't imagine what you *would* do with them.

If you're trying to make `dateutil` be importable, the way to do that is not to do anything with the tarball in your script, but to install the module, which you do from outside your script, before running it. The simplest way to do that is just `pip install dateutil`, which will automatically find the right version of `dateutil`, download it, unpack it, and install it for all of your scripts to use.

That being said, there's really no need for `dateutil` here. If you just subtract two `datetime` objects, you get a `timedelta` object.

---

Meanwhile, the `SyntaxError` comes from this code:

```
if difference_in_years < 18
print ("Sorry, you are not elegible to vote.")
else
print ("You are over 18 and thus elegible to vote.")
```

In Python, compound statements like `if` and `else` need a colon before the suite, and the suite has to be indented. See the [First Steps Towards Programming](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) section of the tutorial. So:

```
if difference_in_years < 18:
    print("Sorry, you are not eligible to vote.")
else:
    print("You are over 18 and thus eligible to vote.")
```

(Also notice that I've removed the space before the parentheses, to fit [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style, and spelled "eligible" properly.)

Comment: My apologies, as I mentioned earlier, I have pretty much no experience with this and your input was very helpful. The reason for the tarball was simply that I became confused whie attempting to resolve the problem and tried to piece together a new code using the answers that I found to other related questions (obviously this didn't work). I have also corrected the spelling error which was an oversight on my part. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the latest date that someone could be born to be 18 without the dateutils module.  So you don't even need to unpack the tarball or really worry about the extra code.  Here is a simple example of calculating the date one would have to be born on to be 18.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today()   # Get a datetime object for today

days = (365 * 18) + (18 / 4)  # calculate days to go back along with leap years
back18 = now - datetime.timedelta(days=days)   # create another datetime object that represents the date the user needs to be to be 18.
```

Then when you create a datetime object from their input, you can just compare them.

```
if birthdate >= back18:
    do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful and I've managed to fix it now.